# Blending techniques

Tags: machine-learning, ensemble-learning

Can anyone explain what is blending in of boosting models and how to combine two models.? How it increases accuracy of model. Any resources are appreciated.
And also, its implementation in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is data blending?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32609/what-is-data-blending)